# Sending account verification email with perl and sendmail/postfix

Tags: perl, email

For my Perl web application, I need account verification via email.

I already have a sub to generate and handle the unique link and an email composing and sending mechanism (with Email::Sender CPAN module) and it works fine - it sends emails and they get delivered.

The problem is they hit spam filters, I think it's because 'From' is 'noreply@example.org' and the user I run a script as is roman@example.org. If I send email with the same exact script with 'From: roman@example.org', it is delivered properly and does not hit the filter.

I have a root privileges on the server and can add users and configure postfix, but the question is what should I do? Run webapp as a user noreply having permissions to send mail? Changing postfix settings? Should I use MDA at all or it's better to stick with Net::SMTP or Email::Sender for a lightweight application?

I understand that an exact answer for that question might help spammers, so general direction and links to documentation I need to read would be enough.

```
from    Example robot noreply@example.org
to  myactualaccount[@]gmail.com
date    Mon, Jun 13, 2011 at 9:45 PM
subject test

hide details 9:45 PM (15 hours ago)

This message is short, but at least it's cheap!
```

Comment: Are you setting the SMTProtocol "envelope" From address? See the [synopsis](http://p3rl.org/Email::Sender#SYNOPSIS). Can you publish an anonymised copy of a mail message that was filtered?

Comment: @daxim I hoped I could get away with the simple form described [here](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Sender-0.110001/lib/Email/Sender/Manual/QuickStart.pm). The email is now in the post, I'll be able to provide more details if necessary in 8-10 hours when I get to another box.

Comment: I take the answer means "no". - Your example email is useless, you have to circumvent the fancy display of your mail client and get at the raw message including the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you are [setting the envelope information](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aSender%3a%3aManual%3a%3aQuickStart#envelope_information).

Also, maybe configure Email::Sender to use the `SMTP` transport rather than `sendmail` and it should set the envelope sender to the same as the `From:` address without interference from postfix.